# how to reach a property in nested objects easily?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a nested object. here it is:

```
var Obj = {
    a: {
        state: {
            started: false,
            players: [],
            hand: 0,
            totalHand: 0,
            teams: {
                starter: {
                    name: "",
                    handPoints: [],
                    totalPoint: calc(Obj.a.state.teams.starter.handPoints)
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Like you see , i need to use `handPoints` value to set `totalPoint`. Do i have to call that like this:

```
calc(Obj.a.state.teams.starter.handPoints)
```

is there some way about using `this` keyword or something else?

What if i had a more nested object? It looks like weird to me.

Thank you.

Comment: do you want the totalPoint to be updated whenever handPoints is modified?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried your solution? It causes a syntax error. Obj isn't defined while you're trying to define it, and even if it was you wouldn't get the latest value of obj, because you're trying to set it as the current value of the array at runtime.

see here:

[syntax error example](http://jsfiddle.net/mPNvH/)

You want to make that property a function so that a user can get the current total when they access the function.

Like this:

```
totalPoint: function(){
   return calc(Obj.a.state.teams.starter.handPoints)
}
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mPNvH/2/)

If you want to shorten the reference you can alias some part of it. For instance

```
totalPoint: function(){
   var myStarter = Obj.a.state.teams.starter;
   return calc(myStarter.handPoints)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could instead make the variable `totalPoint` into a function and use `this`.

```
var Obj = {
    a: {
        state: {
            started: false,
            players: [],
            hand: 0,
            totalHand: 0,
            teams: {
                starter: {
                    name: "",
                    handPoints: [ 5,6 ],
                    totalPoints: function() { 
                        return calc(this.handPoints); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3bDT2/1/).